# How to open a file with UNICODE filename on Windows?

Tags: unicode, fopen

There is a 3rd lib only accept char* filename e.g. `3rdlib_func_name(char* file_name)`. Every things get wrong when I provide a filename in Chinese or Japanese.

Is there any way to make this lib open UNICODE filename?  The program is running on **Windows**.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Go back to the 3rd-party author.

Comment: The library may support UTF-8 filenames, you can't immediately tell by just looking at the function definition (`char*` could be ASCII, or it could be UTF-8). I'm assuming the library uses `fopen` internally, which on *nix does support UTF-8 filenames, whereas on Windows it doesn't (you need to use the platform specific `_wfopen`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We has a similar problem too. Luckily there's a solution, though it's kinda tricky.

If the file/directory already exists - you may use the `GetShortPathName` function. The resulting "short" path name is guaranteed not to contain non-latin characters.

1. Call `GetShortPathNameW` (unicode version) to get the "short" path string.
2. Convert the short path into the ANSI string (use `WideCharToMultiByte`).
3. Give the resulting ANSI string to the stupid 3rd-party lib.

Now, if the file/directory doesn't exist yet - you may not obtain its short pathname. In such a case you should create it first.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this solution. It does not 100 percent work:( We have called the lib supplier this afternoon.

Comment: I would so LOVE to have access to GetShortPathName resp. unicode-named files under Windows7 using PHP...

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't unless you can recompile it from modified source (a major undertaking). You might have better luck feeding the 3rd party library short filenames, like `AHDF76~4.DOC`; these filenames use ASCII. See [`GetShortPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!
I have tried this awesome GetShortPathName. It does work sometimes, but not all the time:)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to convert the string to local code page:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Japanese_Japan.932");
std::string file_name = convert_to_codepage_932(utf16_file_name);
3rdlib_func_name(file_name.c_str());
```

Otherwise?

Blame windows for not supporting UTF-8 `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

The current Windows ANSI code page used on my computer is 1252(retrieve from GetACP). I have tried 3 code pages CP_ACP, CP_UTF8 and 936(Simplified Chinese Code Page) to call WideCharToMultiByte to change a UNICODE Chinese filename to multibyte filename. The 3rdlib_func_name returns "file not found" with all of these 3 multibyte filenames.

Comment: Note. CP_UTF8 is not supported as filesystem code-page. I'd suggest just run tests with fopen and then with 3rd part library.

If does not help stop using Windows `;-)`.

Comment: To be honest, my home computer runs on Ubuntu, but I work on Windows：） I have tried fopen, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @zengkun100 This is known Windows issue. You met such issues almost anywhere when it comes to files opening and the library wasn't developed originally for Windows and UTF-16 support.