# Get the user's codepage name for functions in boost::locale::conv

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, codepages, boost-locale

### The task at hand

I'm parsing a filename from an UTF-8 encoded XML on Windows. I need to pass that filename on to a function that I can't change. Internally it uses [`_fsopen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx) which does not support Unicode strings.

### Current approach

My current approach is to convert the filename to the user's charset hoping that the filename is representable in that encoding. I'm then using `boost::locale::conv::from_utf()` to convert from UTF-8 and I'm using `boost::locale::util::get_system_locale()` to get the name of the current locale.

**Life is good?**

I'm on a German system using code page [Windows-1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx) thus `get_system_locale()` correctly yields *de_DE.windows-1252*. If I test the approach with a filename containing an umlaut everything works as expected.

### The Problem

Just to make sure I [switched my system locale](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/4677) to Ukrainian which uses code page [Windows-1251](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195053.aspx). Using some Cyrillic letter in the filename my approach fails. The reason is that `get_system_locale()` still yields *de_DE.windows-1252* which is now incorrect.

On the other side [`GetACP()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) correctly yields 1252 for the German locale and 1251 for the Ukrainian locale. I also know that Boost.Locale can convert to a given locale as this small test program works as I expect:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Codepage: " << GetACP() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Boost.Locale: " << boost::locale::util::get_system_locale() << std::endl;

    namespace blc = boost::locale::conv;
    // Cyrillic small letter zhe -> \xe6 (ш on 1251, æ on 1252)
    std::string const test1251 = blc::from_utf(std::string("\xd0\xb6"), "windows-1251");
    std::cout << "1251: " << static_cast<int>(test1251.front()) << std::endl;
    // Latin small letter sharp s -> \xdf (Я on 1251, ß on 1252)
    auto const test1252 = blc::from_utf(std::string("\xc3\x9f"), "windows-1252");
    std::cout << "1252: " << static_cast<int>(test1252.front()) << std::endl;

}
```

### Questions

- How can I query the name of the user locale in a format Boost.Locale supports? Using `std::locale("").name()` yields *German_Germany.1252*, using it results in a `boost::locale::conv::invalid_charset_error` exception.
- Is it possible that the system locale remains *de_DE.windows-1252* although I'm supposedly changing it as local admin? Similarly system language is German although my account's language is English. (Log in screen is German until I log in)
- should I stick with [using short filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2735723/1969455)? Does not seem to work reliably though.

### Fine-print

- Compiler is MSVC18
- Boost is version 1.56.0, backend supposedly winapi
- System is Win7, system language is German, user language English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSI is deprecated so don't bother with it.

Windows uses UTF16, you must convert from UTF8 to UTF16 using `MultiByteToWideChar`. This conversion is safe.

```
std::wstring getU16(const std::string &str)
{
    if (str.empty()) return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), 0, 0);
    std::wstring res(sz, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &res[0], sz);
    return res;
}
```

You then use `_wfsopen` (from the link you provided) to open file with UTF16 name.

```
int main()
{
    //UTF8 source:
    std::string filename_u8;

    //This line works in VS2015 only
    //For older version comment out the next line, obtain UTF8 from another source
    filename_u8 = u8"c:\\test\\__ελληνικά.txt";

    //convert to UTF16
    std::wstring filename_utf16 = getU16(filename_u8);

    FILE *file = NULL;
    _wfopen_s(&file, filename_utf16.c_str(), L"w");
    if (file)
    {
        //Add BOM, optional...

        //Write the file name in to file, for testing...
        fwrite(filename_u8.data(), 1, filename_u8.length(), file);

        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "access denined, or folder doesn't exits...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit, getting ANSI from UTF8, using `GetACP()`

```
std::wstring string_to_wstring(const std::string &str, int codepage)
{
    if (str.empty()) return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), 0, 0);
    std::wstring res(sz, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &res[0], sz);
    return res;
}

std::string wstring_to_string(const std::wstring &wstr, int codepage)
{
    if (wstr.empty()) return std::string();
    int sz = WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::string res(sz, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &res[0], sz, 0, 0);
    return res;
}

std::string get_ansi_from_utf8(const std::string &utf8, int codepage)
{
    std::wstring utf16 = string_to_wstring(utf8, CP_UTF8);
    std::string ansi = wstring_to_string(utf16, codepage);
    return ansi;
}
```

Comment: Under the assumption that I cannot change the function this sadly does not help. But this is still promising as the interface is too stable for change but the function only requires effort. Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: The problem you describe is rather complicated, it's part of the reason Unicode was invented in the first place. I added a function to get ANSI from UTF8, it's sort of what Iverelo suggested. See also this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30229657/4603670) about system language, I am not sure if that helps though.

Comment: Fortunately I managed to adopt your first suggestion. It allowed to keep the stable interface but change the internals. I used `boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>()` instead of your `getU()` though.

Comment: Unfortunately there still is no answer to the actual question. But you now provide a way to work around the boost limitation so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Barmak's way is the best way to do it.

To clear up the locale stuff, the process always starts with the "C" locale. You can use the [setlocale function](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%20locale) to set the locale to the system default or any arbitrary locale.

```
#include <clocale>

// Get the current locale
setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL);

// Set locale to system default
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

// Set locale to German
setlocale(LC_ALL,"de-DE");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the locale overloads of the conversion functions don't work with the standard locales. And the charset-as-string overloads fail with the names of these locales even when striping the language_territory part.

Comment: The conversion functions you mention are still the boost functions? Unfortunately I do not have a lot of experience with boost locale functions. The trick I have used to go from one encoding to another in the past on Windows is to use [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) to get to wide characters and then [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) to get back to a different encoding.

Comment: Yes, still the boost functions. I guess internally they do the same, the key question is how the MS uint code page ID is mapped to boost code page strings.